# Is the "CMakeList.txt" file autogenerated or do I have to download it somewhere?

Tags: c, cmake

CMake error:

```
`CMake Error: The source directory "C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/ACCESS/OpenGl" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

I trying to learn the basics of OpenGL using C programming language. I am using MinGW as compiler and SublimeText3 as text editor. I have just installed CMake and read the instructions in the help section, but they do not make clear where to find "CMakeList.txt". Is this file automatically generated?
I am using the GUI CMake interface:

Folder of sorce code: `C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/ACCESS/OpenGl`.
Inside the folder there is a file called: `window.c`

Folder to build the binaries: `C:/Users/Computer/Desktop/ACCESS/OpenGl/build`.

The generator is: `MingGW Makefiles`.

Comment: Are you trying to start your own project or build an existing one?

Comment: Start a new project (open a little window).

Comment: Then you write the CMakeLists.txt yourself.  Plenty of examples and guides available online.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Didn't know abut this